# Bind popup returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-leaflet

I am following the [Covid-19 Map](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cliojOu3as&t=2181s) tutorial by Coding with Adam. When each country is clicked, the popup displays the country's name along with the infection count. The COVID data can be obtained [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/web-data/data/cases_country.csv).

My replicated example cannot properly display the infection count, returning undefined instead of a number.

```
const CovidMap = ({ countries }) => {

    const mapStyle = {
        fillColor:"white",
        weight: 1,
        color:"black",
        fillOpacity: 1,
    };
    
    const onEachCountry = (country, layer) => 
    {
        layer.options.fillColor = country.properties.color;
        const name = country.properties.ADMIN;
        const confirmedText = country.properties.confirmedText;

        layer.bindPopup(`${name} ${confirmedText}`); //confirmedText returns undefined
    };

    return ( 
        <MapContainer style={{height: "90vh"}} zoom={2} center={[20, 60]}>
            <GeoJSON 
            style={mapStyle} 
            data={countries} 
            onEachFeature={onEachCountry} />
        </MapContainer> 
    );
};
```

[image]

I am certain that *confirmedText*'s value can be accessed, because console.log() prints the value. ADMIN and ISO_A3 can be displayed by the popup, but not confirmed nor confirmedText.

UPDATE: Forgot to include the GeoJSON used to build the countries. [Here](https://github.com/CodingWith-Adam/covid19-map/blob/master/src/data/countries.json) it is.

FURTHER UPDATE: If I add any lines to the code that throw an error, remove the lines, and re-render the page, the popup can return the values. However, subsequent re-renderings would introduce the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your SS it doesn't appear that `confirmedText` is a property of your object. Normally objects show in the terminal like `{ prop: 'a',... }` with the ... standing in for much larger object. I'm also curious why you have to access your sub properties using the `properties` key word. In a normal object it would just be `country.confirmedText`. I (me) would start by understanding why you need to access things this way and that might explain why it's `undefined`.

I'd leave this as a comment but I can't do that yet.

Comment: Hi, the GeoJSON has the following format: 
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
                                                                                
  "features": [
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confirmed": some value}}
  ]
}